# Resize gif demo in README

Tags: github, readme

I have two gifs that I want to put side by side in my README.

`![Demo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14092539/27794834-cc32c936-5fd1-11e7-9c37-f2dc5cabe32d.gif)`

`![Demo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14092539/27794978-4fe9c2c0-5fd2-11e7-8a96-28d72fa103d1.gif)`

I  tried to resize them by sticking =250x250 at the end of the addresses and that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, crop them yourself ... If you resize the images to 250×250 nothing will be readable anymore anyway. There's just too much needless padding.

Comment: Alright then, I'll do that. Thank you!